# HTML "Session" on local network

Tags: javascript, html

I'm looking to make a web based card game for people to play with their friends in person (ie substituting playing cards with phones/tablets)

I know this can be done through having an account-based website, but I'm trying to avoid going down that route for now.

Basically what I need (if it's possible) is a way to send data to and from devices on the same wifi when on a particular web page, but various Google searches have not resulted in me getting any idea of where to start. Obviously this is potentially a big task, so all I really need for now is a rough idea of the area of Web development code-wise to research and learn.

What would you suggest be the best place to start?

Comment: Instead of worrying about the front end, you should get yourself familiar with backend first, ie server-side.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 -- I disagree.  There is no need for anything on the backend, so why complicate things?  Also, 我更喜欢跆拳道.

Comment: @Malvolio Currently there is no standardized technology that allows a browser to communicate with another browser without a server in between. I don't see how this is complicating things, when this is the usual way of doing it. Note that even WebRTC requires a server in between for [signaling](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/#toc-signaling).

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 -- signaling may not have a standardized solution, but it's a standardized problem and there are a lot of trivial solutions floating around. [Here](https://shanetully.com/2014/09/a-dead-simple-webrtc-example/) is one that is 17 lines of Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The technology you need is called WebRTC.  It doesn't have to be local, and in addition to simple data like game-play, you can exchange streams of audio and video.

[Here](https://webrtchacks.com/datachannel-multiplayer-game/) is one example.